# Can't get tensorflow-gpu to work in R due to CUDA issues

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to get started using Keras and I have one of the new fancy type of Nvidia GPUs but I can't seem to get it off the ground despite the fact that I'm using a fresh installation of Ubuntu (20.04).

On my first attempt, I noticed that Ubuntu detected my graphics card so I installed it by going into "Additional Drivers." I then installed Keras and Tensorflow using the following commands and yielded no errors.

```
install.packages("keras")
library(keras)

install_keras(tensorflow = "gpu")
```

However, when I try to actually set up a Keras model,

```
model <- keras_model_sequential() %>%
  layer_dense(units = 16, activation = "relu", input_shape = c(10000)) %>%
  layer_dense(units = 16, activation = "relu") %>%
  layer_dense(units = 1, activation = "sigmoid")
```

I get this awful error message:

```
2021-01-14 09:04:53.188680: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_cpu_device.cc:41] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2021-01-14 09:04:53.189214: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2021-01-14 09:04:53.224466: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-01-14 09:04:53.224843: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:09:00.0 name: GeForce RTX 3080 computeCapability: 8.6
coreClock: 1.785GHz coreCount: 68 deviceMemorySize: 9.78GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 707.88GiB/s
2021-01-14 09:04:53.224860: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.11.0
2021-01-14 09:04:53.226413: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.11
2021-01-14 09:04:53.226446: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublasLt.so.11
2021-01-14 09:04:53.226935: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2021-01-14 09:04:53.227061: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2021-01-14 09:04:53.227139: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'libcusolver.so.10'; dlerror: libcusolver.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /home/arta/.local/share/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib:/usr/lib/R/lib:/usr/local/cuda-11.2/lib64:::/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/lib/server:/usr/local/cuda-11.2/lib64
2021-01-14 09:04:53.227437: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.11
2021-01-14 09:04:53.227513: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.8
2021-01-14 09:04:53.227519: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1757] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
2021-01-14 09:04:53.228275: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_gpu_device.cc:99] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2021-01-14 09:04:53.228290: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1261] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021-01-14 09:04:53.228293: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1267]
```

As you might notice, this error message mentions `cuda-11.2`, however, I got an almost identical error message when I was using my system's default `cuda-10.1`, which I suppose came with the driver.

I did a number of things, including downloading and trying to install cuDNN direct from Nvidia's website using their documentation, and adding cuda to `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, to no avail.

Finally, I removed my `r-reticulate` conda environment so that I can reinstall Tensorflow again from scratch but against cuda 11.2 instead of the default 10.1.

I followed the directions on [this blog post](https://medium.com/@stephengregory_69986/installing-cuda-10-1-on-ubuntu-20-04-e562a5e724a0) but I instead substituted every instance of 10.1 with 11.2, and libcudnn.so.7 with libcudnn.so.8, since that's the newest version available and it's the one I downloaded to my system, which brings me to the above error message, which is almost the same as the one I got when I was using 10.1, which came default with my computer.

Also, I noticed something strange when I tried to use Tensorflow in R again. I installed it using `install_keras(tensorflow = "gpu")` with no discernible problems, but when I called the following command:

```
imdb <- dataset_imdb(num_words = 10000)
```

It started downloading and installing it for me once again, but it gave me this warning:

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
tensorflow-gpu 2.2.0 requires tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0, but you have tensorboard 2.4.0 which is incompatible.
tensorflow-gpu 2.2.0 requires tensorflow-estimator<2.3.0,>=2.2.0, but you have tensorflow-estimator 2.4.0 which is incompatible.
```

What am I supposed to make of this? Why is it that it can use the right installation of CUDA:

```
2021-01-14 09:00:06.766462: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.11.0
```

But it can't use another file somewhere else?

```
2021-01-14 09:04:53.227139: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'libcusolver.so.10'; dlerror: libcusolver.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /home/arta/.local/share/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib:/usr/lib/R/lib:/usr/local/cuda-11.2/lib64:::/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/lib/server:/usr/local/cuda-11.2/lib64
```

What do I do now? Why can't I get gpu acceleration to work? My plan is to follow the directions in that blog post and purge all Nvidia software from Ubuntu and try again using 10.1, since that seems to be the most stable version.

Comment: Your TF is expecting to use CUDA 11.0.  You have CUDA 11.2.  You cannot use CUDA 11.2 as a substitute for CUDA 11.0

Comment: @RobertCrovella if I were to purge all of my Nvidia CUDA-related software and graphics card driver and start again, which version of CUDA would you recommend that I use for the best compatibility both with libcudnn and with Tensorflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @RobertCrovella, I uninstalled CUDA, cuDNN etc. because of the version mismatch and reinstalled CUDA version 11.0 with cuDNN 8.0.

```
> tensorflow::tf_gpu_configured()
...
tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1406] Created TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0 with 8779 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce RTX 3080, pci bus id: 0000:09:00.0, compute capability: 8.6)
GPU device name:  /device:GPU:0[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score -2):

do I understand correctly that if I installed cuda 11.0 and cuDNN 8.0 to cuda 11.0 then all these errors disappear?

I have installed cuda 11.2 and found cuDNN 8 to cuda 11.1. I've installed them then with python3 (3.8 ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS default) pip3 and tensorflow etc. In python the rip seems to be working but in R it's broken.
I have created symbolic links to the existing versions and an R code get to the point where it should use the gpu but it is aborted with core dump.

Comment: This had better be posted as a comment, not an answer.